# About Hue's period

Tags: color

So we can see that `Hue` is a periodic function. Its period is 1. And the specifier from documentation. Sorry for I cannot cite my local language documentation. Let me take a look the normal situation:

```
Graphics @ {Hue[-0.33, 1, 1], Disk[]}
```

[image]

But how about this?

```
Image[{{{-0.33, 1, 1}}}, ColorSpace -> "HSB"]
```

[image]

Update the question like this LLlAMnYP, we can see the data will not be adjust to 0~1:

[image]

Comment: re: the update, I don't see this as a contradiction. If `Image` interprets the data in a certain way, there is no need to introduce unnecessary overhead by transforming the data to a "canonical" form.

Comment: On the other hand, this has implications, that come up when using various functions like `ImageSubtract`. I'll add an example to my answer.

Comment: Yeah,I'm look forward to your example,and sorry my poor English that I can understand your "overhead",and for this case,how can I let the pixed of {-0.33,1,1} to display a correct color of Blue?

Comment: I've edited my answer, See also Jason's input.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So LLlAMnYP answered **why** it displays red instead of blue, but it got me to thinking how to make it behave the way OP expected it to.

Here is a comparison of `Hue` inside of `Image` and just by itself:

```
TableForm[
{Table[{n, Image[{{{n, 1, 1}}}, ColorSpace -> "HSB"],
 Graphics[{Hue[n, 1, 1], Rectangle[]}, ImageSize -> 22]}, {n, -2, 0, 0.1}], 
   Table[{n, Image[{{{n, 1, 1}}}, ColorSpace -> "HSB"], 
   Graphics[{Hue[n, 1, 1], Rectangle[]}, ImageSize -> 22]}, {n, 0, 2, 0.1}]}
   ]
```

[image]

So to get it to behave properly, we use `Mod`, with a slight offset so that it doesn't set a brightness value of 1 equal to 0:

```
TableForm[
 {Table[{n, Image[Mod[{{{n, 1, 1}}}, 1, .001], ColorSpace -> "HSB"],
     Graphics[{Hue[n, 1, 1], Rectangle[]}, ImageSize -> 22]}, {n, -2, 
    0, 0.1}], 
     Table[{n, 
    Image[Mod[{{{n, 1, 1}}}, 1, .001], ColorSpace -> "HSB"], 
       Graphics[{Hue[n, 1, 1], Rectangle[]}, ImageSize -> 22]}, {n, 
    0, 2, 0.1}]}
    ]
```

[image]

and your original example is simply

```
Image[Mod[{{{-0.33, 1, 1}}}, 1, .001], ColorSpace -> "HSB"]
```

[image]

Comment: +1, we think alike. As far as my preference goes, `Hue` may be periodic, but brightness and saturation have no reason to be, so I apply `Mod` only to the hue channel. And thanks to periodicity, transforming `Hue` of 1 to 0 isn't much of a problem.

Comment: Yeah - I really wanted to be able to apply the change to the `ColorSpace` itself, as in `ColorSpace->Hue[Mod[#1,1],#2,#3]&` but I can't find any documentation on using a user-defined `ColorSpace`.   You **can** put a `ColorFunction` there, as in `ColorSpace->Hue`, but there seems to be some limit.

Comment: It appears, that the valid option values for `ColorSpace` are quite smart, it accepts `RGB; "RGB", "Hue", "HSB", HSB, Hue` etc. No matter, strings or not, some aren't even defined symbols. I guess it's not intended to take functions, but just strings/symbols of a specific syntax.

Comment: But regardless of the specification, `ImageColorSpace` always then returns the color space in a proper string form (`"HSB", "RGB", etc`).

Answer (score 9):

Hue *is* a periodic function. However, from the documentation:

> Image[data,"type"] coerces values in data to the specified type by rounding or clipping.

So as argument to image, negative hues are equivalent to 0.

Re: comment by Jason B.
This is even more explicitly explained in two nearby lines of the documentation:

> Image[data] is equivalent to Image[data,"Real"].
>   Image[data] by default allows any real number, but displays only values between 0 and 1.

@Yode notes, that the `ImageData` itself is not clipped to `0-1`. At first glance, this doesn't matter, as clipped or not, the output result will be the same. However, consider

```
{im1, im2} = {Image[{{{-.5, .5, .5}}}, ColorSpace -> "HSB"],
                   Image[{{{0., .5, .5}}}, ColorSpace -> "HSB"]}
```

> [image: pixels] `(* Identical appearance, differing ImageData *)`

```
im3 = Image[{{{0., 1., 1.}}}, ColorSpace -> "HSB"]
```

> [image: pixels2]

```
{ImageSubtract[im3,im1], ImageSubtract[im3,im2]}
```

> [image: pixels3]

Thus we subtract from the same image images of identical appearance and get different results. I feel, it's not exactly desirable behavior.

Re: follow-up question in comment:

```
data = {{{-.33, 1., 1.}}}
Apply[{Mod[#1, 1], #2, #3} &, data, {2}]
Image[Apply[{Mod[#1, 1], #2, #3} &, data, {2}], ColorSpace -> "HSB"]
```

> [image: result]

Here's a better approach using specialized image functions (`ImageApply`):

```
im1 = Image[data, ColorSpace -> "HSB"]
ImageApply[{Mod[First@#, 1]}~Join~Rest@# &, im1]
```

> [image: pixels5]

Comment: In this case, OP isn't specifying a "type", but it also says that "Image[data] by default allows any real number, but displays only values between 0 and 1."

Comment: Thanks for your answer and I'll update my question to spectify the case.

Comment: @JasonB duly noted, thanks.

Comment: I'm verry moving to your help and answer like so careful.But the `Jason B`'s solution is more concise I think.And I cannot accept two answer.Thank you once again.